# Go directly to inbox when logging into Yahoo! Mail instead of the "What's new" page

Tags: yahoo-mail

Where can I set up my Yahoo! Mail to automatically take me to my inbox instead of displaying the page that lists all the new items on the "What's New" page?

I want to disable that landing and arrive at the Inbox after sign-in. I get news from the United States and that doesn't interest me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to *Options* → *Mail Options*.

Under *Behavior*, check the *Inbox: Show on startup* box.